# AngularJS watch for list

Tags: angularjs, typescript, color-picker

I am running angularJS application.I am taking color picker and assigning the selected color to the div.my code is working fine for single record. For collection (ng-repeat) if we select any one color for particular entry then that color is assign to all records.My code is as follows

TS(typescript) file

```
let mainAngularModule = angular.module("acc-management", ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);

mainAngularModule.config(routeConfig);

routeConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
function routeConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/it', {
            templateUrl: 'linkmanager.html'
        })
        .when('/UserDefinedElement', {
            templateUrl: 'UserDefinedElementType.html',
            controller: 'userdefinedelementtype as UDETController'
        })
}

class UserTypeRecord {
    public Id: number;
    public Name: string;
    public colorcode: any;
}


class UserDefinedElementTypeController {
    private url: string;
    private token: string;
    public static $inject = ["$scope", '$http', '$q'];
    private TestString: any;

    public mycolor: string = "#f0f0f0";
    public divStyle: any;
    public usertypearray: UserTypeRecord[];


    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {
        this.url = "https://apidev.smartfacts.com/sfit/";

        this.watchForColor();

        this.usertypearray = [
            { Id: 1, Name: "bhushan" },
            { Id: 2, Name: "suryakant" }
        ];
    }

    private watchForColor() {

        this.$scope.$watch(() => this.mycolor,
            (newVal, oldval) => {
                console.log('this.scope', this.$scope);
              this.divStyle = {
                    'background-color': newVal,
                  'color': 'white',
                   'width': '100px',
                    'height': '100px',
                   'font-size': 'large'
              }
          });

    }

}
```

HTML code

```
<div class="demo-md-panel-content">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:15%">Symbol</th>
                        <th style="width:15%">Name</th>
                        <th style="width:15%">Color</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in UDETController.usertypearray">
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <span ng-style="UDETController.divStyle">Testing</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="x.Name" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="color" ng-model="UDETController.mycolor" />
                        </td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

When i select color for particular row/record only that color should be assigned or apply to that particular(row) div it should not be assign to other(rows) div

Answer (score 0):

I red your code better, and I'd like to write my version:

First I would remove completely the watcher inside the controller...

```
let mainAngularModule = angular.module("acc-management", ['ngMaterial', 'ngRoute']);

mainAngularModule.config(routeConfig);

routeConfig.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
function routeConfig($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/it', {
            templateUrl: 'linkmanager.html'
        })
        .when('/UserDefinedElement', {
            templateUrl: 'UserDefinedElementType.html',
            controller: 'userdefinedelementtype as UDETController'
        })
}

class UserTypeRecord {
    public Id: number;
    public Name: string;
    public Color: any;
}


class UserDefinedElementTypeController {
    private url: string;
    private token: string;
    public static $inject = ["$scope", '$http', '$q'];
    private TestString: any;
    public usertypearray: UserTypeRecord[];


    constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope) {
        this.url = "https://apidev.smartfacts.com/sfit/";

        this.usertypearray = [
            { Id: 1, Name: "bhushan" },
            { Id: 2, Name: "suryakant" }
        ];
    }
}
```

...and i would let angular do the job for you:

```
<div class="demo-md-panel-content">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:15%">Symbol</th>
                        <th style="width:15%">Name</th>
                        <th style="width:15%">Color</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="x in UDETController.usertypearray">
                        <td style="text-align:center">
                            <span ng-style="{'background-color': x.Color}">Testing</span>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="x.Name" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="color" ng-model="x.Color" />
                        </td>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Finally I would use a css class for the non dynamic div propriety style:

```
'color': 'white',
'width': '100px',
'height': '100px',
'font-size': 'large'
```

or, if you plan to dynamically change them, replace 
`public: Color`
with a style object and replace

`ng-style="{'background-color': x.Color}"`

with

`ng-style="x.Style"`

Comment: U mean i need to take mycolor in my UserTypeRecord  array? As of now its not in my array so i can't take x.mycolor

Comment: I updated my answer, hope It will be helpful, have a good day.

Comment: In HTML page  ng-style="{'background-color': x.Color}" if we use 'x' it implies obj of 'usertypearray' and we can acess the elements of that array in that loop with help of ng-repeat. In my array i have not taken color as a element of my array, you want me to take color as part of my array?

Comment: Yes, if you look at my example you will see i moved "mycolor" inside "usertypearray" renamed as "Color"if it's what you mean .